# Override generic method in abstract class with concrete type in subclass

Tags: kotlin, generics

I have an main class in Kotlin which defines one concrete and one abstract generic method as follows:

```kotlin
abstract class MainClass {
    abstract fun <TParent, TChild> getChildren(parent: TParent): Array<TChild>?

    fun <TParent, TChild> processChildren(parent: TParent) {
        val children = getChildren<TParent, TChild>(parent)
        // ... do something with children
    }
}
```

As you can see the method is about a parent object of type `TParent` containing child objects of type `TChild`. The parent class and how to get the children from it should be defined by subclasses, which should provide the concrete types.

I did the following:

```kotlin
class MyClass : MainClass{
    override fun getChildren(parent: MyParent): Array<MyChild>? {
        //... some logic getting the children from a parent object
    }
}
```

But that does not work because it won't compile (*'getChildren' overrides nothing*).

How can I define a generic abstract method and implement it with concrete types in a subclass? Note that it is important to me that the generic types are defined on method-level, not on class level!

Comment: "it is important to me that the generic types are defined on method-level, not on class level!" - and this is exactly why it can't be done. What if someone would call `MyClass.getChildren()` passing different types than `MyParent`/`MyChild`?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this. Due to the type erasure the methods signatures will not fit.

What you actually can do is to make this abstract method `protected` and **overload** it with some specific types

```
// protected abstract fun <TParent, TChild> getChildren... 

class MyClass: MainClass() {
    override fun <TParent, TChild> getChildren(parent: TParent): ArrayList<MyChild>? {
        // Some dummy implementation 
        println(parent!!::class.java.canonicalName)
        return null
    }

    fun getChildren(parent: MyParent):  ArrayList<MyChild>? { 
        return getChildren<MyParent, MyChild>(parent)
    }

    fun getChildren(parent: MyParent2): ArrayList<MyChild2>? {
        return getChildren<MyParent2, MyChild2>(parent)
    }
}
```

But not really sure what is the sense of doing this especially if generic types are not bounded

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you don't want the method in one class to process different types of parameters.
In this scenario, make the class generic:

```kotlin
abstract <TParent, TChild> class MainClass {
    abstract fun getChildren(parent: TParent): Array<TChild>?

    fun processChildren(parent: TParent) {
        val children = getChildren<TParent, TChild>(parent)
        // ... do something with children
    }
}

class MyClass : MainClass<MyParent, MyChild>() {
    override fun getChildren(parent: MyParent): Array<MyChild>? {
        //... some logic getting the children from a parent object
    }
}
```